# Converting Month String into Integer Shell

Tags: bash, shell, date, openssl, certificate

okay so i run an openssl command to get the date of an expired script. Doing so gives me this:

```
enddate=Jun 26 23:59:59 2012 GMT
```

Then i cut everything out and just leave the month which is "Jun"

Now the next part of my script is to tell the user if the the certificate is expired or not and to do that i use an if statement in which it looks like this:

```
if [ $exp_year -lt $cur_year && $exp_month -lt $cur_month ]; then
    echo "" 
    echo "Certificate is still valid until $exp_date"
    echo "" 
else
    echo ""
    echo "Certificate has expired on $exp_date, please renew."
    echo ""
fi
```

I can't figure out how to convert the month into an integer to even do the comparison.
I thought of doing the brute force way which is this:

```
Jan=01
Feb=02
Mar=03
...
```

Clearly that's a terrible way to do it. Does anyone know what i can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, you can use:

```
now=$(date +%s)
cert=$(date --date="$enddate" +%s)
if [ $cert -lt $now ]; then
   echo "Old!"
fi
```

i.e. convert the date into the seconds past the epoch and compare those

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Petesh's answer, but here's a way to set up an associative array if you have Bash 4:

```
months=(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
declare -A mlookup
for monthnum in ${!months[@]}
do
    mlookup[${months[monthnum]]=$((monthnum + 1))
done

echo "${mlookup["Jun"]}"    # outputs 6
```

If you have Bash before version 4, you can use AWK to help you out:

```
month=Feb
awk -v "month=$month" 'BEGIN {months = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"; print (index(months, month) + 3) / 4}'
```

Another way in pure Bash (any version):

```
months="Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
month=Aug
string="${months%$month*}"
echo "$((${#string}/4 + 1))"
```

Comment: I love the last answer for its creativeness.